# Making private type to public type APIs

Tags: flutter

I'm having a warning message on ***_WordMarker***
Avoid using private types in public APIs.

```
class WordMarker extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  final int index;

  const WordMarker({required Widget child, required this.index, Key? key})
      : super(child: child, key: key);

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return _WordMarker()..index = index;
  }

  //Warning message on _WordMarker
  @override
  void updateRenderObject(BuildContext context, _WordMarker renderObject) {
    renderObject.index = index;
  }
}

class _WordMarker extends RenderProxyBox {
  late int index;
}
```

I tried following these but I'm still unable to remove the warning message.
["Avoid using private types in public APIs" Warning in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72677634/avoid-using-private-types-in-public-apis-warning-in-flutter)
["AVOID using library private types in public APIs" - lint warning, even in in cookbook examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72545964/avoid-using-library-private-types-in-public-apis-lint-warning-even-in-in-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remove the "_" from _WordMarker and change it to MyWordMarker and the warning disappears.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this lint rule in analysis_options.yaml File & set the value to false to avoid these warnings.

```
library_private_types_in_public_api: false
```

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helped you out. If so, I would appreciate if you could accept my answer  If you still have questions, feel free to ask 

Comment: I think there must be some "reasonable grounds" of this warning. why should we go around ? but not solve ?